# SQL: Returning Columns of multiple tables and DATEDIFF in minutes

Tags: sql, t-sql, datediff

Attempting to retrieve columns from 3 different tables, with the TurnTime's being DATEDIFF's from a 4th table

`CustomerName, OrderTypeName, LoanNumber, TurnTime1, TurnTime2,TurnTime3, TurnTime4`

Tables:

`tblCustomer, tblOrderType, tblOrder, tblOrderActivity, tblActivity`

I am running into syntax errors when I place my DATEDIFFs. I assume I am doing it very wrong and am trying to get the difference in the times.

The following table is used in tblOrderActivity for DATEDIFF

```
tblActivity      ActivityID                ActivityName
                      1                      Received
                      2                       Keyed
                      3                      Printed
                      4                      Delivered
```

I want to find the DATEDIFF from 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 1-4. `ActivityID` and `ActivityDate` are in `tbl.OrderActivity`

I attempted to put a `(Select DATEDIFF` with the `INNERJOIN` of the tables I am desiring to retrieve the dates from, however, it also led to syntax errors.
Here is my current code:

```
SELECT   
dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerName, dbo.tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, dbo.tblOrder.LoanNumber, 
dbo.tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate, 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ActivityID=1, ActivityID=2) AS TurnTime1, 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ActivityID=2, ActivityID=3) AS TurnTime2,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ActivityID=3, ActivityID=4) AS TurnTime3,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ActivityID=1, ActivityID=4) AS TurnTime4
FROM     
dbo.tblOrder 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblCustomer ON dbo.tblOrder.CustomerID = dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblOrderActivity ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderID = dbo.tblOrderActivity.OrderID AND 
    dbo.tblOrder.OrderID = dbo.tblOrderActivity.OrderID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblActivity ON dbo.tblOrderActivity.ActivityID = dbo.tblActivity.ActivityID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblOrderType ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderTypeID = dbo.tblOrderType.OrderTypeID


ORDER BY dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerName, dbo.tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, dbo.tblOrder.LoanNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
SELECT   
dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerName, dbo.tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, dbo.tblOrder.LoanNumber, 
a1.ActivityDate, 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a1.ActivityDate, a2.ActivityDate) AS TurnTime1, 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a2.ActivityDate, a3.ActivityDate) AS TurnTime2,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a3.ActivityDate, a4.ActivityDate) AS TurnTime3,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a1.ActivityDate, a4.ActivityDate) AS TurnTime4
FROM     
dbo.tblOrder 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblCustomer ON dbo.tblOrder.CustomerID = dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblOrderActivity a1 ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderID = a1.OrderID and a1.activityid = 1
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblOrderActivity a2 ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderID = a2.OrderID and a1.activityid = 2
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblOrderActivity a3 ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderID = a3.OrderID and a1.activityid = 3
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblOrderActivity a4 ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderID = a4.OrderID and a1.activityid = 4
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblOrderType ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderTypeID = dbo.tblOrderType.OrderTypeID
ORDER BY dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerName, dbo.tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, dbo.tblOrder.LoanNumber
```

Ketil

Comment: That seems to execute, but no rows of any columns are returned

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance in the final code Ketil.
Here is the full functioning and working solution to my problem.

```
SELECT   
dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerName, dbo.tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, dbo.tblOrder.LoanNumber, 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a1.ActivityDate, a2.ActivityDate) AS [TurnTime1], 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a2.ActivityDate, a3.ActivityDate) AS [TurnTime2],
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a3.ActivityDate, a4.ActivityDate) AS [TurnTime3],
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a1.ActivityDate, a4.ActivityDate) AS [TurnTime4]
FROM     
dbo.tblOrder 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.tblCustomer ON dbo.tblOrder.CustomerID = dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.tblOrderActivity a1 ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderID = a1.OrderID and a1.ActivityID = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.tblOrderActivity a2 ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderID = a2.OrderID and a2.ActivityID = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.tblOrderActivity a3 ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderID = a3.OrderID and a3.ActivityID = 3
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.tblOrderActivity a4 ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderID = a4.OrderID and a4.ActivityID = 4
INNER JOIN
dbo.tblOrderType ON dbo.tblOrder.OrderTypeID = dbo.tblOrderType.OrderTypeID
ORDER BY dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerName, dbo.tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, dbo.tblOrder.LoanNumber, a1.ActivityDate;
```